# Автозаполнения файла xsd из готовой модели базы данных Django

Tags: python, django, xsd, python-docx

Как реализовать автозаполнения формы в xsd из готовой базы данных? Допустим, есть клиент данные которого уже заведены в базу. Жмём по кнопке и отправляется готовый файл для скачивания с заполненной формой xsd. Пример не полной формы прикрепляю:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2013 (http://www.altova.com) by  () -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:usch="http://www.unisoftware.ru/schematron-extensions" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Файл">
        <xs:annotation>
            <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
            <xs:appinfo>
                <sch:pattern name="Проверка имени файла на соответствие значению атрибута @ИдФайл">
                    <sch:rule context="Файл">
                        <!--  Проверка имени файла на соответствие ИдФайл  -->
                        <sch:assert test="usch:getFileName() = @ИдФайл">
                            <usch:error code="0400400007" path="@ИдФайл" value-of-select="@ИдФайл" doc-id-path="usch:getFileName()" doc-id-caption="Файл">Имя файла обмена "<usch:value-of select="usch:getFileName()"/>" не совпадает со значением элемента ИдФайл "<usch:value-of select="@ИдФайл"/>"</usch:error>
                        </sch:assert>
                    </sch:rule>
                </sch:pattern>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
            <xs:documentation>Файл обмена</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Документ">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Состав и структура документа</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="СвНП">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Сведения о пользователе контрольно-кассовой техники</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:choice>
                                        <xs:element name="НПЮЛ">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Пользователь - организация</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="НаимОрг" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>Наименование организации</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                            <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ИННЮЛ" type="ИННЮЛТип" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>ИНН</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="КПП" type="КППТип" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>КПП</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ОГРН" type="ОГРНТип" use="optional">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>ОГРН</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="НПФЛ">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Пользователь - физическое лицо, зарегистрированное в качестве индивидуального предпринимателя</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="ФИО" type="ФИОТип">
                                                        <xs:annotation>
                                                            <xs:documentation>Фамилия, имя, отчество физического лица, зарегистрированного в качестве индивидуального предпринимателя</xs:documentation>
                                                        </xs:annotation>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ИННФЛ" type="ИННФЛТип" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>ИНН физического лица, зарегистрированного в качестве индивидуального предпринимателя</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ОГРНИП" type="ОГРНИПТип" use="optional">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>ОГРНИП</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:choice>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Подписант">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Присутствие сведений о представителе в  зависимости  от  значения  ПрПодп">
                                            <sch:rule context="Подписант">
                                                <!-- Контроль обязательности присутствия Сведений о представителе налогоплательщика в зависимости от значения ПрПодп -->
                                                <sch:assert test="usch:iif(@ПрПодп=2, count(СвПред)!=0, (count(СвПред)!=0 or count(СвПред)=0))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ПрПодп" value-of-select="@ПрПодп">Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствия) элемента Файл/Документ/Подписант/СвПред при значении элемента ПрПодп, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ПрПодп"/>".</usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---*******************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Присутствие ФИО в  зависимости  от  значения  ПрПодп и ИдентМЧД">
                                            <sch:rule context="Подписант">
                                                <!-- Контроль обязательности присутствия ФИО в зависимости от значения ПрПодп -->
                                                <sch:assert test="usch:iif(((@ПрПодп=2 and count(./СвПред/ИдентМЧД) = 0))  or (@ПрПодп=1 and ../СвНП/НПЮЛ)), count(ФИО)!=0, (count(ФИО)!=0 or count(ФИО)=0))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="ФИО" value-of-select="count(ФИО)">Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/Подписант/ФИО при значении элемента ПрПодп, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ПрПодп"/>".</usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---*******************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:documentation>Сведения о лице, подписавшем документ</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ФИО" type="ФИОТип" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Фамилия, имя, отчество</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="СвПред" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Сведения о представителе заявителя</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="НаимДок" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>Наименование документа, подтверждающего полномочия представителя</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                            <xs:maxLength value="120"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ИдентМЧД" use="optional">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>Идентификатор машиночитаемой доверенности</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                            <xs:maxLength value="120"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ПрПодп" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Признак лица, подписавшего документ</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличияРегНомерККТ">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия РегНомерККТ при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @РегНомерККТ) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@РегНомерККТ))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@РегНомерККТ при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрИзмАдрМУ">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрИзмАдрМУ при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрИзмАдрМУ) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрИзмАдрМУ))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрИзмАдрМУ при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрСменОФД">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрСменОФД при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрСменОФД) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрСменОФД))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрСменОФД при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрИзмАвтУстр">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрИзмАвтУстр при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрИзмАвтУстр) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрИзмАвтУстр))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрИзмАвтУстр при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрЗамФН">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрЗамФН при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрЗамФН) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрЗамФН))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрЗамФН при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрЭлектрРежим">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрЭлектрРежим при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрЭлектрРежим) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрЭлектрРежим))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрЭлектрРежим при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрАвтономРежим">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрАвтономРежим при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрАвтономРежим) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрАвтономРежим))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрАвтономРежим при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрИзмНаимНП">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрИзмНаимНП при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрИзмНаимНП) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрИзмНаимНП))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрИзмНаимНП при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрИныеПричины">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрИныеПричины при ВидДок=2        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=2 and @ПрИныеПричины) or (@ВидДок=1 and not(@ПрИныеПричины))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ВидДок" value-of-select="@ВидДок">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствие) элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/@ПрИныеПричины при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ВидДок"/>".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия МоделФН">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия МоделФН при ВидДок=1        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=1 and СведРегККТ/@МоделФН) or (@ВидДок=2) ">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="" value-of-select="">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/СведРегККТ/@МоделФН при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "1".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ЗаводНомерФН">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ЗаводНомерФН при ВидДок=1        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=1 and СведРегККТ/@ЗаводНомерФН) or (@ВидДок=2) ">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="" value-of-select="">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/СведРегККТ/@ЗаводНомерФН при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "1".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрАвтоном">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрАвтоном при ВидДок=1        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=1 and СведРегККТ/@ПрАвтоном) or (@ВидДок=2) ">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="" value-of-select="">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/СведРегККТ/@ПрАвтоном при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "1".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрЛотерея">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрЛотерея при ВидДок=1        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=1 and СведРегККТ/@ПрЛотерея) or (@ВидДок=2) ">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="" value-of-select="">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/СведРегККТ/@ПрЛотерея при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "1".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Проверка наличия ПрАзарт">
                                            <sch:rule context="ЗаявРегККТ">
                                                <!--             Обязательность присутствия ПрАзарт при ВидДок=1        -->
                                                <sch:assert test="(@ВидДок=1 and СведРегККТ/@ПрАзарт) or (@ВидДок=2) ">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="" value-of-select="">
                                                        Не выполнено условие присутствия элемента Файл/Документ/ЗаявРегККТ/СведРегККТ/@ПрАзарт при значении элемента ВидДок, равном "1".
                                                    </usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <!---
```